# How do you groupby/summarise by 3 of 4 categorical variables?

Tags: r

I have a categorical variable I want to group by and summarise with a numeric variable.

I only want to group by 3 of the 4 levels in the categorical variable. How do I filter out the fourth level?

```
df %%
group_by(CategoricalVariable) %%
summarise (
name = mean(NumericVariable, na.rm = TRUE))
```

I thought putting filter() to remove the fourth level would work:

```
df %%
group_by(CategoricalVariable, filter(Level4) %%
summarise (
name = mean(NumericVariable, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or naming the 3 levels of the variable I want would do it but its not working:

```
df %%
group_by(CategoricalVariable, "Level1", "Level2", "Level3") %%
summarise (
name = mean(NumericVariable, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[CategoricalVariable != 'Level4'
   , .(mean = mean(NumericVariable, na.rm = TRUE))
   , CategoricalVariable
   ]
```

Comment: I tried adding in the part you mentioned but its still not working - any ideas? 

df %%
group_by[CategoricalVariable !='Level 4' %%
summarise (name = mean(NumericVariable, na.rm = TRUE),(name = median(NumericVariable, na.rm = TRUE))]

Comment: Did u get an error message? If so, what was it? If not, what did u mean by not working?